# WatchKit Error - no notification payload

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, xcode6.3, ios8.2

I'm receiving the following error, even though I added the `NotificationPayload.apns` file to my project.

> WatchKit Error - no notification payload. Add a payload to your WatchKit extension to populate your notification controller.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your scheme is set up correctly. Check here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW8

> To test your notification interface with the JSON payload, configure the build scheme with the appropriate payload file. When you select a notification interface executable, Xcode adds a menu for choosing one of your payload files. You can create different build schemes for different notification payloads, or you can update the payload file for an existing build scheme before testing.

Comment: But how do you ensure that your apns file is populated in the "Notification Payload" menu? I've added my apns to the WatchKit App and the extension targets, but it still isn't showing up in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this message if your JSON payload file isn't valid JSON. You can always validate it at http://jsonlint.com to be sure.